# Heap space being taken up by MemoryMXBean NotificationListener

Tags: java, jmx

How much memory will JMX Notification Listeners use up?

I have a Java 7 application with a small Max Heap.

I was monitoring it with a single MemoryMXBean notification listener and most of the Heap got used up. Memory Analyser report:

> One instance of "com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ArrayNotificationBuffer"
>   loaded by "system class loader" occupies 16,810,416 (52.18%) bytes.
>   The instance is referenced by
>   sun.management.NotificationEmitterSupport$ListenerInfo @ 0xeda6d9e0 ,
>   loaded by "system class loader". The memory is accumulated in one
>   instance of "java.lang.Object[]" loaded by "system class loader".

My code

```
final MemoryMXBean mbean = ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(mBeanServerConnection, MEMORY_MXBEAN_NAME, MemoryMXBean.class);
NotificationEmitter emitter = (NotificationEmitter) mbean;
emitter.addNotificationListener(new NotificationListener() {
    @Override
    public void handleNotification(Notification notification, Object handback) {

        if (notification.getType().equals(MemoryNotificationInfo.MEMORY_THRESHOLD_EXCEEDED)) {
            LOG.info("Memory threshold exceeded !!!");
        }

        if (notification.getType().equals(MemoryNotificationInfo.MEMORY_COLLECTION_THRESHOLD_EXCEEDED)) {
            LOG.error("Memory Collection threshold exceeded !!!");
        }

    }
}, null, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an inner class, like NotifcationListener in you code, the class gets a hidden field that holds a reference to the object in which the instance was created.

You can fix the memory leak by declaring your inner class static,

```
static class LogListener implements NotifciationListener {
  @Override
  public void handleNotification(Notification notification, Object handback) {
    LOG.info("Notification!"); 
  }   
}
```

and then create an instance like this

```
 MemoryMXBean mbean = ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(mBeanServerConnection,
    MEMORY_MXBEAN_NAME, MemoryMXBean.class);
 NotificationEmitter emitter = (NotificationEmitter) mbean;
 emitter.addNotificationListener(new LogListener());
```